# Initialize list - specified number of objects c#

Tags: c#, list

Items is public list of MenuListItemViewModel items, in example below im creating new list with 2 elements:

```
        Items = new List<MenuListItemViewModel>
        {
            new MenuListItemViewModel
            {
                Value = "500",
                Letter = "D"
            },
            new MenuListItemViewModel
            {
                Value = "-500",
                Letter = "W"
            },

        };
```

How to do exactly the same but with variable numbers of items i want to have in the list? Something like loop x times (like below, but it wont work in current state)

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                new MenuListItemViewModel
                {
                  Value = "500",
                  Letter = "D"
                },
             }
```

Comment: You can't. You can only run this at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
Items = new List<MenuListItemViewModel>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Items.Add(
            new MenuListItemViewModel
            {
              Value = "500",
              Letter = "D"
            });
}
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ`:

```
Items = Enumerable.Range(0, number)
  .Select(i => new MenuListItemViewModel
  {
    Value = "500",
    Letter = "D"
  }).ToList();
```